# Undoing git add and git commit and kind of git push origin

Tags: git, github

I am new to github and was just mainly using only "git add", "git commit" and "git push origin".

I had a pretty big zipped file, let's call it big.zip (around 1 GB), and wanted to upload it to my git repository so I did:

```
git add big.zip
git commit -m "this is my big file"
git push origin
```

It started to upload it, but after some time I decided I didn't want it any more so I typed ctrl+c.

Now I cannot see my big.zip in my repository, obviously, but I want to remove everything from the "git add zone". For example, if I want to push a tiny txt file I am seeing:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Citing objects:  96% (28/29)
```

So I am guessing there are 39 or 29 files in the "add zone" waiting to be pushed to the repository and the big fat big.zip is also there. How do I flush it all? I tried git reset, git clean, git remove from index, git gtfo and it all ain't working.

Is there an easy way to get rid of it all? I want to drop everything that is in "add zone" and the files that were on their way to the repository.

And one more thing: I do not have the .zip file locally any more and I don't remember the name of it. If I type git ls-files, I don't see the .zip file on the list.

Thank you for your time,
Mateusz.

Edit: Of course I don't want to proceed with git push origin, because the .zip file is too big and don't want it in my git repository. If this sounds stupid, please ignore it and take it as a necessity.

EDIT2: 
Here is what happened:
when I typed git status I got:

```
On branch master
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.

 Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../diag/blabla.pdf
    ../mod/tab6
    ../tej.txt
```

Which is not what I wanted to see, because there is no big .zip file there and I know there is one. If I go git push origin, something big is clearly being uploaded.

What I did, was typed "git push origin" anyway, because I have to proceed with my project. The big file is somehow uploaded, I can see it in the commit history (it says "binary file removed" though) and I cannot see it in the repository. It seems I cannot download it either (I hope its just a text information about it).

Problem of my head, but question remains open: how do I stop git from uploading a file (lets say it wasn't 800 MB, but 800 GB and I really don't want to wait till its finished?).

Answer (score 0):

Run `git status`, it will show you the staged changes (the index). You can then `git rm someFile` to remove files from the index and `git commit` the rest later on.

You might need to force push your branch to the remote later, tho (`git push -f origin master`).